# Using Visual Studios 2013 and VB.net, how to capitalize lets in a textfield mixed with numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I am and entry level programmer and i have a task that is asking me to modify a page that takes and entry from a textfield that is mixed with letters and numbers. this field is called a "job#" and then the page will search a database for that in particular job. problem is that it only searches it if its in capital letters. need to have it accept caps and lower case letters. it is in VB.net. and i went to the controller and i have this code here

```
 Try
    res.success = True
    res.message = ""
    Dim r = New Objects.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest(jobNumber)
    Dim req = New ViewModels.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest(r)
    Models.Core.Approvals.AddIApprovableToCache(r)
    res.data = req
    Return New PCA.Core.Web.JSON.JSONPResult() With { _
         .Data = res,
         .Callback = callback
        }
```

i tried to tack on "ToUpper() after the (jobnumber) because i thought that is where it takes the number entered and applies it to a variable to search the database for it. but it says that 'ToUpper()' is not a member of 'Trident.Objects.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest' im assuming the parent class doesnt have the package where ToUpper() is ?

Comment: What is `jobNumber`, a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i tried to tack on "ToUpper() after the (jobnumber) because i thought
>   that is where it takes the number entered and applies it to a variable
>   to search the database for it. but it says that 'ToUpper()' is not a
>   member of 'Trident.Objects.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest'

Instead of

```
Dim r = New Objects.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest(jobNumber).ToUpper()
```

use

```
Dim r = New Objects.Business.Capital.CapitalRequest(jobNumber.ToUpper())
```